# Weblogic 12 c Eclipse Kepler Spring deploy error

Tags: eclipse, spring, weblogic12c, kepler

I work with Eclipse Kepler, Weblogic 12.1.2, Spring 3.2.6.RELEASE.

When I deploy the application from Eclipse Weblogic, I get the following error message

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context   
initialization failed
\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\eusurvey\beadep\test1\eusurvey\WEB-INF\classes\com\ec\survey\controller\ActivityController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.ec.survey.controller.ActivityController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:875)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
```

ActivityController.java is

```
package com.ec.survey.controller;

import com.ec.survey.model.*;
import com.ec.survey.model.administration.User;
import com.ec.survey.model.survey.Survey;
import com.ec.survey.service.*;
import com.ec.survey.tools.ConversionTools;
import com.ec.survey.tools.Ucs2Utf8;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{shortname}/management")
public class ActivityController extends BasicController {

@Resource(name = "sessionService")
private SessionService sessionService;

@Resource(name = "administrationService")
private AdministrationService administrationService;

@Resource(name = "surveyService")
private SurveyService surveyService;

@Resource(name = "activityService")
private ActivityService activityService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/activity")
public ModelAndView activity(@PathVariable String shortname, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Form form;
```

Could this error be why this controller doesn't find the other java classes?

How can I fix this error?

EDITED: The full trace is

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context 

initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activityController' defined in file [C:\Users\excp0019\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\eusurvey\beadep\test1\eusurvey\WEB-INF\classes\com\ec\survey\controller\ActivityController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.ec.survey.controller.ActivityController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:875)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:715)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:522)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:348)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:283)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:117)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.declaredAnnotations(Method.java:714)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:700)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:388)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:870)
... 53 more
<16-jun-2016 12H12' CEST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined  
listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed:   
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating  
bean with name 'activityController' defined in file [C:\Users\excp0019   
\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects 
\eusurvey\beadep\test1\eusurvey\WEB-INF\classes\com\ec\survey\controller 
\ActivityController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class  
com.ec.survey.controller.ActivityController] failed; nested exception   
is  

 java.lang.ArrayStoreException


sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating   


 bean with name 'activityController' defined in file [C:\Users\excp0019
   \workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects  
   \eusurvey\beadep\test1\eusurvey\WEB-INF\classes\com\ec\survey\controller 
   \ActivityController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class 
   com.ec.survey.controller.ActivityController] failed; nested exception is 

  java.lang.ArrayStoreException:  
  sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:875)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:715)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:522)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:117)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace>
INFO : com.ec.survey.ShutdownListener - Context initialize<16-jun-2016   
12H12' CEST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load    
user defined filter in web.xml:     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activityController' defined in file [C:\Users\excp0019\workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\eusurvey\beadep\test1\eusurvey\WEB-INF\classes\com\ec\survey\controller\ActivityController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.ec.survey.controller.ActivityController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:875)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:715)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:522)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:348)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:283)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:117)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: And the full stack trace is????

Comment: Attach the full stack trace